# Compiling Wine 1.7.1 from git in Gentoo

Tags: compiling, wine

Trying to compile Wine 1.7.1 with the great new D3D and Opengl patches.
I proceed like this :

1-Download the GIT source code from here : https://github.com/tpruzina/wine-1.7.1-d3dstream_patches-gentoo_compat_patches

2-Run the script the author made to build both 32 bit and 64 bit libs, wich is basically create 2 directories one for each arch and configure / make

3- The configure goes kind of well for what I see but then the make crashes badly here :

```
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/cf/Downloads/wine-1.7.1-d3dstream_patches-gentoo_compat_patches-master/wine64/dlls/dxguid'
make: *** No rule to make target `dlls/ntoskrnl.exe/ntoskrnl.exe.spec', needed by `dlls/ntoskrnl.exe/libntoskrnl.exe.def'.  Stop.
```

Full configure and make logs here :

http://pastebin.com/vRZpUVH1

Thank you !

Comment: What's your question??

Comment: Why the compilation crashes ? I have all the needed libs and patched it  with the Gentoo compat patch wich makes it compile on Gentoo ... no idea of why it crashes.

Comment: Looks like a bug, I recommend asking the developer. This is a problem that cannot be solved without analysing the source code.